# Integrating WireGuard into Swift macOS App

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, wireguard

I'm attempting to integrate the wireguard-apple package into my macOS Xcode project. [enter link description here](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-apple). I've followed the instructions in the README, but I keep getting this error when building the project:

[image]

This is how I have the project structure set-up:

[image]

And how I have the External Build System target configured:

[image]

It's not clear to me what other steps if any are needed that aren't included in the repository's readme. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I am having the same exact issue.  Were you able to resolve?

Comment: @shirefriendship sadly no :/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you try the following procedure.

1. Check that the `go` language is well installed.
2. check `$(GOROOT)`.

- How to check `$(GOROOT)`

```
% go env GOROOT
/usr/local/go
```

3. Now, In Xcode, enter `Target` -> your `External Build System` -> `Build Settings`.
4. Enter `PATH` : `GOROOT`/bin. (Enter your GOROOT.)

[image: Build Settings]

I had the same problem a few months ago and found the above solution through searching, but unfortunately I didn't write down the original article, so I can't give you the original post.

Anyway, I hope this solves your problem.